# Jquery returning NaN with span tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, nan

I am trying to utilize an averaging system that is pretty simple but for whatever reason Jquery won't return the values from the span tags.

```
<span class="rating"></span>
```

Here is my fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/uTuYH/1/

Comment: your code *needs* to be included in your question.

Comment: Spans don't have values. If you're looking for the value stored in an attribute, use the .attr method. Additionally, you never actually set the value attribute, therefore it stays ""

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uTuYH/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
          $(".rating").each(function () {
              var ratingValue = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
              total = total + ratingValue;
              console.log(ratingValue);
          });
```

Getting text:

```
$(this).text()
```

Instead of:

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using data attributes if anything here. You're applying value to an element that doesn't standardly support that, or I should say it is unconventional use since technically it may work, but more widely accepted practices may precede the use of value on a span tag. Especially since data attributes exist and are supported.

Try `<span class="rating" data-rating="5"></span>`

Then in your rating function you access

```
$(this).data('rating')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not html inputs you are getting the value of so you can't use `.val()`, use `.text()` instead:

```
var ratingValue = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTuYH/11/

Answer (score 0):

The div has no attribute named "Value". You need to use .text() or .html()

```
var ratingValue = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
```

or

```
var ratingValue = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
```